# Uniform convergence of the series $f(t)=te^{-t^2}$ over $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

> Define $f_n(t)=te^{-t^2}$. Does $f_n$ converge uniformly over $[0,1]$? If we change the definition to $f_n(t)=nt^n(1-t)$ does this satisfy the conditions of uniform continuity?

Idea: firstly consider the definition of uniform continuity. We have $f_n(t)$ is uniformly continuous iff given any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ for which given any $n\ge N$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. In the first case, there is no dependence of $f_n(t)$ on $N$. So I am inclined to say that $f_n(t)$ converges uniformly to $te^{-t^2}$ - I just need a bit of guidance on how to justify this.

For the second part, I want to manipulate the uniform continuity condition once again: for any $\epsilon>0$ we want some $n$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $|nt^n(1-t)-f(t)|<\epsilon$. Since $t\in[0,1]$ we have $t^n\to 0$ for large $n$, so we want to prove that $f_n(t)$ converges to the zero function. But I can't see how to do this.

Comment: $f_{n} (t) =f(t) $, the difference is zero, so <positive real, there's nothing to prove

Comment: Thanks! How about the second case?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part:
Your intuition is correct. $f_{n}(t)\to f(t)$, where $f$ is the zero function.
However, by Theorem 7.9 of Rudin ($f_{n}\to f$ uniformly iff sup$|f_{n}(t)-f(t)|\to 0$), the convergence is not uniform.
Looking into the proof of this theorem should help you understand why.